# Python Selenium access inner elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

Just for fun, I try to extract the scheduled games for day 1 of this NFL season.
As of now, I have this code in Python

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.headless=True

#browser = driver(options=opts)
print("Start")

website = "https://www.nfl.com/schedules/2020/REG1"
browser.get(website)
gamedays = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nfl-o-matchup-group")))
   
print ("There are: ", len(gamedays))
```

This prints "There are: 3" which is correct because there are three sections having that class.
How can I dig deeper into each section?
For example, there is an element having the game date and of course, there are elements having the home team and the away team.

I have tried

```
   for j in range(0,len(gamedays)):
      game_on = gamedays[j].find_elements_by_class_name('d3-o-section-title')
      print(game_on)
```

which prints

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d8807c1ca013d7a2d58bd7377b42ca1a", element="034de32d-bf64-4544-94aa-d97ed6640367")>]
```

That is not helpful.

So, how can I get to that information?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `print(game_on.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Loop through objects returned in `game_on` and print their `innerHtml`

```
print(game_on.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

OR

```
for element in game_on:
   print(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

Comment: The for loop did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Using the line of code:

```
print(game_on)
```

you were printing the element and you need to print the *textContent* instead.

---

### Solution

To print the *textContent* e.g. **Friday, September 11th**, etc you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  browser.get(website)
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nfl-o-matchup-group")))])
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  browser.get(website)
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nfl-o-matchup-group")))])
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Hm, 
print(game_on.text) shows 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

print(game_on.get_attribute("innerHTML")) shows
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Thanks for the links.

Comment: @Michael I assumed the `for` loop was already in your code trials, so I avoided it. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the other solution in the meantime.